# What are some ways to determine the cause of discs not spinning?

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

I have the original PS3 launch model (CECHA01) and it appears my Blu-ray drive has failed; it no longer spins any type of discs. But I'm unsure if this is due to the laser or a mechanical issue.

What's the best way to determine the issue if I'm looking to fix it myself?

Comment: Could you get your hands on another blu-ray drive from another PS3 and swap them out?

Comment: @Robotnik Well yes, but that'll just leave me with a different PS3 unable to read discs.

Comment: you misunderstand, if you can get a differently-broken PS3 (such as one that's dead via yellow light of death) The Blu-Ray drive won't be missed. Ask around at repair shops, game shops etc, they might have a broken spare PS3 lying around they're willing to give away/sell cheaply

Answer (score 1):

Issues like this are covered by warranty, but if your warranty has expired, you can buy a bricked PS3 from eBay, or the like, and swap out the Blu-Ray drives. Whether that is a more feasible alternative to buying a new PS3 depends on how far away the bricked PS3 you buy is; over seas shipping tends to make it a very costly purchase, especially when buying things as large as a PS3 console.

The procedure of swapping the Blu-Ray drives isn't an awfully complex task, and you can find many, many references and instructional videos showing the whole process step-by-step on the web.

To appease to your actual question at hand: like Ekonion said, it's most likely a mechanical issue. Had the laser been broken, the plate would've spun up, and the PS3 would've reported the disc as unreadable or of unknown format.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, the disc **starts** to spin only if the laser is defective. I myself had this issue. If it doesn't even start to spin, the problem is with the motor, and as such is a mechanical issue.